# @TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin) Not working Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I am trying to do a `gradle test` and I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class grails.test.mixin.hibernate.HibernateTestMixin due to missing dependency org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsWebApplicationContext
```

It appears this is related to

`@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)`

Also added dependencies:

```
testCompile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:5.0.5.RELEASE'
testCompile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:5.0.5.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this import `grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsWebApplicationContext` in place of 
`org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsWebApplicationContext`